# Verbindung mit/zu?

Tags: preposition

What is the difference between both expressions? from what I found online it seems like Verbindung **zu** means a link to the while with **mit** it means combination.

But still I am not sure I could use these expressions with confidence.

Is there even a more general rule behind the use of *mit* and *zu* in other contexts?

Answer (score 4):

Your example varies based on the context. And there is no general rule since "zu" and "mit" (especially "zu") have different meanings if they are adverb, preposition or anything else.

If we look at

> Der Gegenstand stand in Verbindung mit dem Fall.

There "Verbindung mit" means that the object was *connected* with the case. But another example with "mit":

> In Verbindung mit Sauerstoff ist Wasserstoff gefährlich.

This expresses that oxygen is dangerous *in combination* with hydrogen.

And the same problem occurs with "zu":

> Sie hatte eine Verbindung zu einem WLAN-Netzwerk.

This expresses (again) a *connection* (she was connected to a WiFi). But of course there's also another meaning:

> H und O<sub>2</sub> gingen eine Verbindung zu H<sub>2</sub>O ein.

That sentence expresses a link. And there are more example for "mit" and for "zu". But as stated at the beginning that really depends on the context and especially on the substantive.

Comment: Vielen Danke
When the association is with an animate or an abstract concept (authority, state) which preposition is preferred?

Comment: @Averroes Do you want an association (that would also be the German term "Assoziation") or a combination or a connection?

Comment: 1) his relationship with his boss is undergoing a real change.
2) Our relation to state is a matter of debate.

Is there a correspondence between the use of to/with in English and  zu/mit in German?

Seemingly with to in English we refer to unchanging relations.

Comment: 1) Seine Beziehung zum Chef verändert sich wesentlich. 2) Unsere Beziehung/Verbindung zum Staat ist Diskussionssache. I would not use "Verbindung" in the first case. But I don't know if there's any real rule for changing or unchanging relations in German.

Comment: My guess is that Verbindung mit is either used with "in", to convey the sense of in regards to, in combination with. Otherwise when no preposition precedes it. It merely means "communication with". Could you confirm that please? Many thanks

Comment: @Averroes I do not exactly understand what you mean (especially that part with "communication with").

Comment: Verbindung mit dem Himmel, mit einem Anrufer. It does not merely mean relation but rather communication. Other than that, we have the expression "in Verbindung mit" wich means "in combination with" or "has a relationship with".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55615/discussion-between-texnician-and-averroes).

Answer (score 0):

**Verbindung:** An das Substantiv *Verbindung* wird gewöhnlich mit der Präposition *mit* angeschlossen: *in Verbindung mit jemandem stehen, sich mit jemandem in Verbindung setzen. Die Eintrittskarte gilt nur in Verbindung mit dem Personalausweis. Aber die Greisin hielt überhaupt nur eine sehr lose Verbindung mit ihm aufrecht* (Brecht). An *Verbindung* wird auch mit *zu* angeschlossen, vermutlich in Analogie zu dem Substantiv *Beziehung: in Verbindung zu / mit* *jemandem treten. Du sollst ihm rasch eine Verbindung zu sozialen Kreisen verschaffen* (Musil). Gelegentlich tritt auch der Anschluss mit *von, zwischen* oder *aus* auf: *die Verbindung von Metallteilen durch Schweißen; durch Löten eine Verbindung zwischen zwei Drähten herstellen; Wasser ist eine Verbindung aus Wasserstoff und Sauerstoff*. Alle diese Formen des Anschlusses sind korrekt.

(c) Duden ‒ Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle, 8. Aufl. Berlin 2016

- Duden-Empfehlung ist *in Verbindung mit*

Comment: Die Frage wurde auf Englisch gestellt und sollte dementsprechend auf Englisch beantwortet werden. Ein Nicht-Muttersprachler könnte Schwierigkeiten haben, den zitierten deutschen Text zu verstehen.